# React Native Firestor

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

i need some help. I want add User to a collection Users after they signed up.
I found this Solution:

```
export const signup = (email, password, callback) => {
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(() => {
      firebase.firestore().collection('Users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .set({
          email: email,
          name: '',
          pastor: false,
          picture: ''
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Something went wrong with added user to firestore: ', error);
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      callback(error.message);
      console.log('Something went wrong with sign up: ', error);
    })
}
```

But now i get this warning after i signed up.

Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 3301286ms)

But I do not understand where is the timer from and how can i fix this?

Can anybody help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried the proposed solutions on the thread you posted? anything else in your code that might  be using timers? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981#issuecomment-303542392

Comment: No, there is no timer set anywhere. But the message disappears if you comment out the code in "then" during the successful authentication, so don't add a user to the Users collection So what does it means.?